# reloading a page after every 1min in rails3.1

Tags: javascript

I am building a rails app i want to reload a page if a user staies on that page for more than a minute. there use to be a page.reload method in rails but it does not work any more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would achieve this in JavaScript, like so:

```
# 60000ms = 60 seconds
setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.reload()
}, 60000);
```

Comment: Not so good with javascript only try to use plugins but let me ask to get an understandind. does it mean that window.location means that present window that is open.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put a meta tag in the head of the web page.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with JS...
Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload= function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.reload();
     }, 60000);
    }
</script>
```